# How to use BCEL in java programming?

Tags: java

Is BCEL(Byte code Engineering Library) directly usable in normal java 1.6 or we need to download something for using it?
Or is this an in built library in java1.6?

Comment: I'd suggest using ASM instead. (There is a private copy of BCEL in the Sun/Oracle JRE, but it's not a good idea to use that.)

Answer (score 3):

It's not built in at all.  You'll have to add the BCEL JARs to your CLASSPATH and write code in your app to use it.

Comment: There happens to be a copy (with package prefix renamed) in the normal Sun/Oracle JRE. It's used to translate XSLT stylesheets into classes.

Answer (score 3):

I would not use BCEL. It seems to be more or less dead. Use ASM instead.

Answer (score 1):

They are in com.sun packages, I would avoid the ones which come with the jdk; I agree with 
both jmg and duffymo